# Page count of UICollectionView with paging in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uipagecontrol, uicollectionview

Consider a `UICollectionView` with flow layout and paging enabled (by setting `pagingEnabled` to `YES`).

What would be the simplest way of obtaining the total number of pages?

And where would be the most appropriate place to update the total number of pages (given that it might change if items are added/deleted, the size of the collection view changes or the layout changes)?

Answer (score 8):

The right answer should be:

> If the UICollectionView scrolls horizontally:

```
int pages = ceil(self.collectionView.contentSize.width /    
                   self.collectionView.frame.size.width);
```

> If it scrolls vertically:

```
 int pages = ceil(self.collectionView.contentSize.height /    
                   self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
```

follow to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions):

> In mathematics and computer science, the floor and ceiling functions
>   map a real number to the largest previous or the smallest following
>   integer, respectively. More precisely, floor(x) is
>   the largest integer not greater than x and ceiling(x)
>   is the smallest integer not less than x.

Here is my result to check:

```
ceil(2.0/5.0) = 1.000000
ceil(5.0/5.0) = 1.000000
ceil(6.0/5.0) = 2.000000
ceil(10.0/5.0) = 2.000000
ceil(11.0/5.0) = 3.000000
```

Answer (score 6):

If the `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally, you divide its `contentSize`'s width to its frame's width:

```
int pages = floor(self.collectionView.contentSize.width /    
                  self.collectionView.frame.size.width) + 1;
```

If it scrolls vertically, you divide its `contentSize`'s height to its frame's height:

```
int pages = floor(self.collectionView.contentSize.height /    
                  self.collectionView.frame.size.height) + 1;
```

Comment: That assumes that there is no spacing, and that all items have the same width or height.

Comment: Couldn't you use `ceil` instead of getting `floor` and adding 1?

Comment: Wouldn't using `ceil` be *more* accurate, since if the `content.width` and `frame.size.width` are equal, you end up with `2`, when there is technically only one page?