# Scroll Cell of CollectionView to Left and Right While Clicking On left&right Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

Actually I have got visible cell of `UICollectionView` like this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.obj_CollectionView1 visibleCells]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.obj_CollectionView1 indexPathForCell:cell];
       lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];

        if (lastIndex ==9) {
            [self.rightButton setHidden:YES];
        }
        if (lastIndex==0) {
            [self.leftButton setHidden:YES];
        }
        if (lastIndex>3) {
            [self.leftButton setHidden:NO];
        }
        if (lastIndex<6) {
            [self.rightButton setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Now by using that index path I want to scroll left and right but I am confused what to write in newIndexPath

```
-(IBAction)RightButton:(id)sender
{
   if (lastIndex <4 && lastIndex >9) 
   {
     [_obj_CollectionView1 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
   }

}
```

and similarly for left button

Please help
\

Answer :

```
NSUInteger lastIndex;
NSIndexPath *indexPathOf;
NSMutableArray *indexContainer;
NSInteger  IndexVisibleCell,IndexVisible;
NSArray *labelcontent;
NSArray *reversedArray;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

    _obj_CollectionView1.delegate = self;
    _obj_CollectionView1.dataSource = self;

    indexContainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:15];
    labelcontent = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"];


}




-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    InnerCollectionCell1 *innerCell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"innerCell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    innerCell.innerViewCell1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;

    innerCell.innerViewCell1.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    innerCell.innerLabelCell1.text = [labelcontent objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    return innerCell;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [labelcontent count];
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGFloat Width = _obj_CollectionView1.frame.size.width-20;

    float cellWidth =Width / 3.0;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth,_obj_CollectionView1.frame.size.height );

    return size;

}

-(IBAction)RightButton:(id)sender
{
       NSMutableArray *pat = [[ _obj_CollectionView1 indexPathsForVisibleItems] mutableCopy];

    [pat sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        NSInteger r1 = [obj1 row];
        NSInteger r2 = [obj2 row];
        if (r1 > r2) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        if (r1 < r2) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    NSIndexPath *pathh = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[(NSIndexPath *)[pat lastObject]item ]+1 inSection:0];

        [self.obj_CollectionView1 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:pathh atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];

}


-(IBAction)LeftButton:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableArray *pat = [[ _obj_CollectionView1 indexPathsForVisibleItems] mutableCopy];
      [pat sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSInteger r1 = [obj1 row];
        NSInteger r2 = [obj2 row];
        if (r1 > r2) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        if (r1 < r2) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];


    NSIndexPath *pathh = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[(NSIndexPath *)[pat firstObject]item ]-1 inSection:0];

        [self.obj_CollectionView1 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:pathh atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      IndexVisible = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];

    if (IndexVisible==labelcontent.count-1)
    {
        [self.rightButton setHidden:YES];
    }
    if (IndexVisible<[labelcontent count]-3)
    {
        [self.rightButton setHidden:NO];
    }
    if (IndexVisible >2) {
        [self.leftButton setHidden:NO];
    }
    if (IndexVisible<1) {
        [self.leftButton setHidden:YES];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.obj_CollectionView1 visibleCells]) {
        indexPathOf = [self.obj_CollectionView1 indexPathForCell:cell];
        lastIndex = [indexPathOf indexAtPosition:[indexPathOf length] - 1];

        if (lastIndex==labelcontent.count-1)
        {
            [self.rightButton setHidden:YES];
        }
        if (lastIndex<[labelcontent count]-3)
        {
            [self.rightButton setHidden:NO];
        }
        if (lastIndex >2) {
            [self.leftButton setHidden:NO];
        }
        if (lastIndex<1) {
            [self.leftButton setHidden:YES];
        }

    }}
```

Comment: I allowed myself to edit your message ; it hurts my eyes to see a capital letter on every single word except the first person **I**

Comment: @Narendra Pandey have u resolved it. i am facing same thing , could u update by answering ur question

Comment: @Imran Hey  You can check It. if still problem arise inform me

Comment: @NarendraPandey sure i will check it today and let u know.. thanks bro

Comment: @NarendraPandey awesome bro. it does work

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say , there should be max 3 items should be visible at a time,Right??

If so create UICollectionViewFlowLayout attributes such that there will be max 3 will be visible

```
- (void)calculateCollectionLayout
{
    [self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kMargin, kMargin, kMargin, kMargin)];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout);
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:kPadding];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:kMargin];
    CGFloat cellWidth = ((CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - (kNumberOfColumns + 1) * kPadding) - (2 * kMargin)) / kNumberOfItemsToBeVisible ;
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth,cellHeight)];

    [layout invalidateLayout];
}
```

In the Above code **kNumberOfItemsToBeVisible** will be 3

And to show/hide right and left button keep track of the currentlyLoadedItems based on the total items

For Example currentPage will be 3  and  left will be hidden initially (if it is <= 3 hide right and left button). When Right is clicked increase it by 3. and check if it is >= totalItems .if yes hide right button. And if currentpage is 1 hide left button again

Comment: actually it works Perfect as i have Used - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    CGFloat Width = _obj_CollectionView1.frame.size.width-20;
    float cellWidth =Width / 3.0;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth,_obj_CollectionView1.frame.size.height );
    
    return size;
    
}

Comment: But The Problem is that i canot able to handle Left or Right Button action

Comment: You should manage it by tracking the currentPage or the way i have asked you to do.

Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433432/page-count-of-uicollectionview-with-paging-in-ios for paging